# Why Dynamically added rows are not getting CSS Class?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am adding dynamic row using jQuery.

Elements are coming perfectly but is not working as expected.

While I am selecting one select-option it is giving it's corresponding values. But in dynamic row it is not giving.

[image]

And also not getting CSS class also.

My jQuery Code:

```js
$(".btn-add").click(function(){
    var markup = 
        "<tr>"+
            "<td>"+
                "<select class='js-example-basic-single' name='product_id[]'"+
                    "<option value='0'>Select Product</option>"+
                    "@foreach($products as $product)"+
                    "<option value='{{ $product->id }}'>{{ $product->productName }}</option>"+
                    "@endforeach>"+
                "</select>"+
            "</td>"+
            "<td>"+
                "<input class='form-control' type='text' name='itemDescription'/>"+
            "</td>"+
            "<td>"+
                "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='itemCost[]'/>"+
            "</td>"+
            "<td>"+
                "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='itemQuantity[]'/>"+
            "</td>"+
            "<td>"+
                "<button class='btn btn-danger btn-remove'>-</button>"+
            "</td>"+
        "</tr>";

    $("table tbody").append(markup);
});
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] it's just a guess, but -> [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: you are trying to add blade's `@foreach` into rendered HTML code. it won't work

Comment: @RomanBobrik, Why it will not work? Data is coming correctly.

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist are you missing class for the option tag?

Comment: because blade rendered once you have got your view from server side. then you are trying to execute blade shortcut on the client side. but all you will get here - `@foreach` as a string in your markup

Comment: If you see, the textboxes are getting the css styles. It is your dropdown where the 'form-control' class is missing. Please add the same to <option> tag.

Comment: @ssBarBee, yes.

Comment: Did that fix it?

Comment: I am not using ```form-control``` class for that.

Comment: Anyone can suggest me to do it in other ways....

Comment: are you using any library for your dropdowns ? maybe re-initing the library after adding a new record fix the problem

Comment: I think you are using select2 library, please call `.select2()` after adding new row

Comment: It's simple, previous lines have JS applied which creates their own classes. So for you, you need to apply the JS to that new line

Comment: @MohammadOlfatmiri, I have added ```$('.js-example-basic-single').select2();```. But not working!!

Comment: check this [Initialising select2 created dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972399/initialising-select2-created-dynamically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about your CSS because you did not post it.
I don't know anything about how you attach the `select2` for the same reason but you could simply add it using an event you can trigger, this is the best I could do without more information but it should give you something to work with.

```js
$("table.my-table").on('select-added', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
  }).on('click', '.btn-remove',
  function(event) {
    let item = {
      rowid: "someIDtoDelete"
    };
    // wild assumption on desire here
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    //now what else? assume something server side
    $.ajax({
      url: "removeRowURL",
      type: "POST",
      data: item
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      alert(textStatus);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert(textStatus);
    });

    $(".btn-add").on('click', function() {
      var markup =
        "<tr><td>" +
        "<select class='js-example-basic-single' name='product_id[]'" +
        "<option value='0'>Select Product</option>" +
        "@foreach($products as $product)" +
        "<option value='{{ $product->id }}'>{{ $product->productName }}</option>" +
        "@endforeach>" +
        "</select></td>" +
        "<td><input class='form-control' type='text' name='itemDescription'/></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='itemCost[]'/></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='itemQuantity[]'/></td>" +
        "<td><button class='btn btn-danger btn-remove'>-</button></td>" +
        "</tr>";

      let tb = $("table.my-table").find("tbody");
      tb.append(markup);
      tb.find('tr').last().trigger('select-added');
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" integrity="sha256-FdatTf20PQr/rWg+cAKfl6j4/IY3oohFAJ7gVC3M34E=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/js/select2.full.min.js" integrity="sha256-vdvhzhuTbMnLjFRpvffXpAW9APHVEMhWbpeQ7qRrhoE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="my-table">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
<button class="btn-add">Add</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But your remove button is not working.

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist To be clear, that was not part of the question and your original code had nothing regarding that button either.  That is a simple issue to resolve by just adding an event handler to the table targeting the button class