# Populating the data from ajax response into an dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi I am new to jquery and ajax I had a dropdown where I will get the data from database using ajax but I am getting issue while populating that data into an dropdown here is the fiddle here I had taken the response in an variable and populated

```js
//Store in array()
$(document).ready(function () {
    addOne();
       $('.drop').select2();
   
});

var uids = [];

//Select option function
$(document).on("change", ".drop", function() {
  $('#seedoc').data().enabled = 1; //set data-enabled to true instead of disabled = false


  //Find option selected
  var data = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-id')

  //Push selected data-id
  uids.push(data)

  //Enable button on selection
  $('#seedoc').prop('disabled', false)
  $('#seedoc').css('color', 'green');



})
$(document).on("click", "#seedoc", function(e) {

  const count = $('.drop').length;
  let sum = 0;

  $('.drop').each(function(e, elem) {
    sum += (parseInt($(elem).val()) > 0);
  });

  if (sum == count) addOne();

});

//Send
function send() {
  console.log(uids)
}

//response
var res = {
  "users": ["<p style='margin:0px;display:none;'data-id='755'>amilham</p>",
    "<p style='margin:0px;display:none;'data-id='706'>a_sarabi</p>"
  ]
}


function getEmails() {
  res.users.forEach(function(option) {
    $('.drop').append('<option value="' + $(option).attr('data-id') + '"" data-id=' + $(option).attr('data-id') + '>' + option + '</option>');
  });
}

function addOne() {
$('#seedoc').css('color', 'gray');


  $('#email-list-container').append("<div class='form-group' style='display:flex'><select class='drop form-control' name='option' id='option'> <option value='0' disabled selected>Select your option</option> </select><select class='form-control'  style='margin-left:1rem' name='cars' id='permissions'><option value='1'>edit</option><option value='2'>view only</option></select>");
  getEmails();

}
getEmails();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.3.1/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.3.1/select2.min.css" type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />

<div id="email-list-container" class=""></div>
<i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" id="seedoc" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;" data-enabled="0"></i>
```

Here the problem is I am getting the same data for every dropdown on click of add button but here in the firstdropdown I am getting two names and when I click add and check the first dropdown again I am getting
the two names doubled i.e 4 options but I want to show only two options in every dropdown whenever I check

Please help me

Comment: Inside function `getEmails()` you are appending to `$('.drop')` every time `+` button is clicked, which means items are added to already existing. You need to do a `$('.drop').empty()` if you like to use `.append()` but replace the items. You can also do `.html()` that will replace current items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [.last](https://api.jquery.com/last/) function in your `getEmails` - `append` function to make sure that you are not appending to the new option to every drop down as you have same classes `.drop`.

This will *ensure* you are **not** appending the option to **all** the `dropdowns` but only the last one.

**Demo**

```js
//Store in array()
$(document).ready(function() {
  addOne();
});

var uids = [];

//Select option function
$(document).on("change", ".drop", function() {
  $('#seedoc').data().enabled = 1; //set data-enabled to true instead of disabled = false

  //Find option selected
  var data = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-id')

  //Push selected data-id
  uids.push(data)

  //Enable button on selection
  $('#seedoc').prop('disabled', false)
  $('#seedoc').css('color', 'green');
})

$(document).on("click", "#seedoc", function(e) {

  const count = $('.drop').length;
  let sum = 0;

  $('.drop').each(function(e, elem) {
    sum += (parseInt($(elem).val()) > 0);
  });

  if (sum == count) addOne();

});

//Send
function send() {
  console.log(uids)
}

//response
var res = {
  "users": ["<p style='margin:0px;display:none;'data-id='755'>amilham</p>",
    "<p style='margin:0px;display:none;'data-id='706'>a_sarabi</p>"
  ]
}


function getEmails() {
  res.users.forEach(function(option) {
    $('.drop').last().append('<option value="' + $(option).attr('data-id') + '"" data-id=' + $(option).attr('data-id') + '>' + option + '</option>');
  });
}

function addOne() {
  $('#seedoc').css('color', 'gray');
  $('#email-list-container').append("<div class='form-group' style='display:flex'><select class='drop form-control' name='option' id='option'> <option value='0' disabled selected>Select your option</option> </select><select class='form-control'  style='margin-left:1rem' name='cars' id='permissions'><option value='1'>edit</option><option value='2'>view only</option></select>");
  getEmails();

}
getEmails();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />

<div id="email-list-container" class=""></div>
<i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" id="seedoc" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;" data-enabled="0"></i>
```

Comment: a small help I had used select2 plugin for implementing search option for dropdown for first dropdown it is working but from second dropdown it is not working can you please help me
@AlwaysHelping

Comment: @swith You need to use event delegation for your dynamically created elements to be able to use select2 on those elements.  This is how events are deletegated =>
`$(document).on("click", "#seedoc", function(e) {})` this

Comment: I didnt got it can you edit in your answer if you dont mind

Comment: @swith Check here [Its a very detailed answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972399/initialising-select2-created-dynamically) and show exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: how can I use this answer in my case here

Comment: Try this => `$('.drop').last().select2()` add this code after the append function in `getEmails()`

Comment: ya an easy answer its working thank you man great! :)

Comment: @swith Happy to help always. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this line:

```
$('.drop').append('<option value="' + $(option).attr('data-id') + '"" data-id=' + $(option).attr('data-id') + '>' + option + '</option>');
  });
```

To this line, which will ensure that only the last dropdown gets the options added to it:

```
$('.drop').last().append('<option value="' + $(option).attr('data-id') + '"" data-id=' + $(option).attr('data-id') + '>' + option + '</option>');
  });
```

Comment: Not an ideal solution Because => `:last` Selector pseudo-class is deprecated since jQuery 3.4 - Its not recemended to offer solution based on deprecated function.