# Clone <tr> tag table with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-select2

I have this form

```html
<form method="POST" id="postPengajuan">
  <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nama_bagian" class="">Nama Kegiatan</label>
          <textarea name="nama_bagian" id="nama_bagian" class="form-control" rows="1"><?= $dataKegiatan->nama_kegiatan ?></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nama_pengaju" class="">Nama Pengaju</label>
          <select id="nama_pengaju" class="single-select" name="nama_pengaju">
            <?php foreach ($dataUser as $data) : ?>
            <?php if ($data->role_id == 1 || $data->role_id == 3) : ?>
            <option value="<?= $data->nama_lengkap ?>">
              <?= $data->nama_lengkap ?>
            </option>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="tanggal" class="">Tanggal</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control date" name="tanggal" id="tanggal">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nama_teknisi" class="">Nama Teknisi</label>
          <textarea name="nama_teknisi" id="nama_teknisi" class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="nip_ppk" class="">NIP PPK</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nip_ppk" id="nip_ppk">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
      <h4>Detail Pengajuan</h4><br>
    </div>
    <table class="table tableDetail">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Ruangan</th>
          <th>Nama Barang</th>
          <th>Jumlah</th>
          <th>Keterangan</th>
          <th>Aksi</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select class="single-select" name="id_ruangan[]">
                <?php foreach ($dataRuangan as $data) : ?>
                <option value="<?= $data->id_ruangan ?>">
                  <?= $data->nama_ruangan ?>
                </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select class="single-select" name="id_barang[]">
                <?php foreach ($dataBarang as $data) : ?>
                <option value="<?= $data->id_barang ?>">
                  <?= $data->nama_barang ?>
                </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="number" min="1" class="form-control" id="jumlah" name="jumlah[]" value="1">
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea id="keterangan" name="keterangan[]" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" id="tambahRow"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Tutup</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="tambahPengajuan">Simpan</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

And I have a jQuery function to clone `<tr>` elements from the `<tbody>` section.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tambahRow').click(function() {
        var clone = $('table.tableDetail tbody tr').first().clone();
        clone.find('input, textarea').val('');
        clone.find('#tambahRow').attr('id', 'deleteRow').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-danger').html('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>');
        $('table.tableDetail tbody').append(clone);
    });

    $('table.tableDetail').on('click', '#deleteRow', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
});
```

But there's a problem with the `select` tag that has the attribute `class="single-select"` here. The issue is with the select2 library. When I clone it, the select2 library doesn't work properly. Instead, it displays as a regular input tag without the ability to scroll and select options. Can you please help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: It is recommended to provide a [mcve]. You seem to have provided an excessive amount of HTML and haven't included the select2 JS that you mentioned.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to PHP? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: @NicoHaase my bad with that tag, well i'll try add this '
`
row.find('select').each(function() {
                var select = $(this);
                select.select2();
            });
`
to recall select2 library function. But if I do that, the original select element will revert back to its initial state as a regular select tag without the select2 instance class.

Comment: Your text describes select2 not working, but there is no select2 code shown.  What are you trying to do with select2?  Do you want to instantiate a new select2 on your newly cloned HTML?  Have you tried calling `.select2()` on it? 
 There are many answers here already if you search for "*select2 clone*", likewise for "*select2 dynamic*", but without knowing what you're trying to do we can't help much.  Random egs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29972399/6089612, https://stackoverflow.com/q/17175534/6089612, ...

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage), select2 is applied to a select element when you call `$('.js-example-basic-single').select2();` on it.

Presumably this removes the original selector element, replaces it with a different set of HTML elements, and adds some event listeners to them.

When you clone your row, you are cloning everything inside it: Including those elements but **not** the event handlers.

If you look at [the documentation for clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) you will see:

> **withDataAndEvents (default: false)**
> Type: Boolean
> A Boolean indicating whether event handlers should be copied along with the elements. As of jQuery 1.4, element data will be copied as well.

… an optional argument **which you aren't using** which will copy event handlers. Adding that *might* be sufficient to fully clone the select2 functionality.

If it isn't, consider using a [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) to source your new DOM nodes from, and explicitly call `select2()` on the newly created `<select>` node after copying from  your template to the place you want to put it.

Comment: If I create an HTML template for my DOM, then I also need to make an AJAX request to fetch data for assuming it was Ruangan and Barang. I don't want to write HTML code inside JavaScript (jQuery).

Comment: @AnonymousUID — I have no idea Ruangan and Barang is, or why you would need to involve Ajax to fetch data for a template when you don't for cloning an element already in the table. I never suggested writing HTML code inside JavaScript.

Comment: To clarify "*this removes the original selector*" - this *hides* the original `<select>` which is then updated by select2 and POST'd with the form.

Comment: *"don't want html in jquery"* - good idea, that's why you clone existing html - the issue is that you're cloning the *wrong* HTML - you're cloning a *working* line - instead, add a `<template>` element when you build the page and clone that - assuming you don't apply `.select2()` to the template, you'll be good to go - no need for an ajax call as you're not doing that at the moment.

Comment: If you don't want to use a `<template>` then do what we did before `<template>` existed - have a second table with `style=display:none` or even a display:none `tr` in the existing table - as long as you don't apply `.select2` to it.